# Python Scattertext cannot generate HTML

Tags: python-3.x, windows, spacy

Cannot generate HTML visualization from sample code. Need help fixing the errors.

Errors:

Warning (from warnings module):

File "C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scattertext\TermDocMatrixWithoutCategories.py", line 154
    corpus_unigram_freq = corpus_freq_df.ix[[term for term

FutureWarning: 
.ix is deprecated. Please use
.loc for label based indexing or
.iloc for positional indexing

See the documentation here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated

Environment:
Windows 10 1903, 
Python 3.7.0

## Code:

```
import scattertext as st
import spacy
from pprint import pprint
convention_df = st.SampleCorpora.ConventionData2012.get_data()  
convention_df.iloc[0]
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')               
corpus = st.CorpusFromPandas(convention_df, 
                             category_col='party', 
                             text_col='text',
                             nlp=nlp).build()
term_freq_df = corpus.get_term_freq_df()
term_freq_df['Democratic Score'] = corpus.get_scaled_f_scores('democrat')
term_freq_df['Republican Score'] = corpus.get_scaled_f_scores('republican')
html = st.produce_scattertext_explorer(corpus,
          category='democrat',
          category_name='Democratic',
          not_category_name='Republican',
          width_in_pixels=1000,
          metadata=convention_df['speaker'])
open("Convention-Visualization.html", 'wb').write(html.encode('utf-8'))
```

Expected result here: https://jasonkessler.github.io/Conventions-Visualization.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning is caused by older versions of Scattertext. You can run `pip install -U scattertext` to remedy this.

Note that this shouldn't prevent the code from running, and you should see the file Convention-Visualization.html in your current working directory.

Comment: Thank you, @JasonKessler. I've upgraded pandas to 0.25.1 yet the warning still shows. And you're right the html worked.

Comment: Just realized you are the author of the demo code, Jason Kessler! Your scattertext demos are awesome from which I've learned so much! Thank you! It'd be great if you can provide a demo of help desk support tickets analysis (ranking unique phrases with tf-idf, etc.).

Comment: Ah. I think you need to upgrade your Scattertext package as well. Please use `pip install -U scattertext` to do this, since the version on conda is outdated.

Comment: Also, if you're interested in looking at tf.idf scores instead of the Dense Rank Difference or the Scaled F-Score, please see [https://github.com/JasonKessler/scattertext/blob/master/demo_cred_tfidf.py] for an example of how to use a newer variant of tf.idf weights (Yoon Kim and Owen Zhang. Implementation of Credibility Adjusted Term Frequency: A Supervised Term Weighting Scheme for Sentiment Analysis and Text Classification. WASSA 2014.) For phrases see [https://github.com/JasonKessler/scattertext/blob/master/demo_phrase_machine.py] for using the integrated PhraseMachine to extract phrases.

Comment: Thank you so much!  But it appears those two examples are no longer available?

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow markdown, and I put an extra bracket around the URLs.  Here's are the correct links: Credibility TF.IDF: https://github.com/JasonKessler/scattertext/blob/master/demo_cred_tfidf.py and Phrases: https://github.com/JasonKessler/scattertext/blob/master/demo_phrase_machine.py

Comment: Hi @JasonKessler, is the score in the phrase machine demo tf-idf score? Thanks.